# Tensorflow/tfjs "When inputs is an array, neither initialState or constants should be provided"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js

I am trying to make a ChatBot using python (tensorflow/keras) for making, training and converting the neural network and then using it in my Angular app with tensorflow/tfjs. I was following the example found here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/tree/master/translation but trying to add an embedding layer as well.

Creating the model:

```
latent_dim = 200
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(encoder_max_length, ), dtype='int32', )
encoder_embedding = Embedding(num_tokens,
                             embedd_size,
                             weights=[word2em],
                             input_length=encoder_max_length,
                             mask_zero=True,
                             trainable=False
                             )(encoder_inputs)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True)(encoder_embedding)
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(decoder_max_length, ), dtype='int32', )
decoder_embedding = Embedding(num_tokens,
                             embedd_size,
                             weights=[word2em],
                             input_length=decoder_max_length,
                             mask_zero=True,
                             trainable=False
                             )(decoder_inputs)
decoder_LSTM = LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True, return_sequences=True)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_LSTM(decoder_embedding, initial_state=encoder_sates)
decoder_dense = Dense(num_tokens, activation='softmax')
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Creating encoder / decoder models (tfjs):

If I remove 'initialState' from LSTM.apply() the error disappears but the result is the same sentence no matter the input.

```
prepareEncoder(model) {
    const encInputs = model.input[0];
    const stateH = model.layers[4].output[1];
    const stateC = model.layers[4].output[2];
    const encoderStates = [stateH, stateC];
    this.encoder = tf.model({inputs: encInputs, outputs: encoderStates});
  }

  prepareDecoder(model) {
    const tmp = model.layers[4].output[1];
    const latentDim = tmp.shape[tmp.shape.length - 1];

    const decoderStateInputH = tf.input({shape: [latentDim], name: 'decoder_state_input_h'});
    const decoderStateInputC = tf.input({shape: [latentDim], name: 'decoder_state_input_c'});
    const decoderStateInputs = [decoderStateInputH, decoderStateInputC];

    const decoderLSTM = model.layers[5];
    const decoderInputs = model.input[1];
    const decoderEmbedding = decoderLSTM.input[0];

    const applyOutputs = decoderLSTM.apply(decoderEmbedding, {initialState: decoderStateInputs});
    let decoderOutputs = applyOutputs[0];
    const decoderStateH = applyOutputs[1];
    const decoderStateC = applyOutputs[2];

    const decoderStates = [decoderStateH, decoderStateC];
    const decoderDense = model.layers[6];
    decoderOutputs = decoderDense.apply(decoderOutputs);

    this.decoder = tf.model({
      inputs: [decoderInputs].concat(decoderStateInputs),
      outputs: [decoderOutputs].concat(decoderStates)
    });
  }
```

Predicting with the model:

```
  botReply(input_seq) {
    let states_value = this.encoder.predict(input_seq);
    let target_seq = tf.buffer([1, data['dec_max_length']], 'int32');
    target_seq.set(dict['<START>'], 0, 0);
    let stop_condition = false;
    let decoded_sentence = '';
    let word_count = 1;
    while (!stop_condition) {
      let predict_outputs = this.decoder.predict([target_seq.toTensor()].concat(states_value));
```

And this is where it all fails and I get the following error:

```
ERROR Error: When inputs is an array, neither initialState or constants should be provided
    at standardizeArgs (recurrent.js:54)
    at LSTM.apply (recurrent.js:465)
    at execute (executor.js:275)
    at training.js:856
    at engine.js:307
    at Engine.scopedRun (engine.js:317)
    at Engine.tidy (engine.js:306)
    at Module.tidy (globals.js:166)
    at training.js:839
    at engine.js:307
```

Things that might be worth mentioning.

- The problem only appears in tfjs. In python it works fine and the results are decent given the dataset and training epochs. And the inference models are made in the exact same way is in tfjs
- Back when i wasn't using the embedding layer and only one-hot encoded vectors for inputs and outputs it worked so i doubt it's a version problem or sth.
- The embedding is made with word2vec on the same dataset as the training of the model.
- I convert the keras model with tfjsconverter.

Any help will be deeply appreciated because I really am running out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - remove 'mask_zero=True' from your Embedding layers and see if this resolves the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the late response but yes your solution was correct. Thank you.